# How to mock a class which contain a variable that can throw NPE

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito

I have a login presenter which I want to test. I am new to unit testing and I have written a basic test to test a small functionality.

```
class LoginPresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val view: LoginView,
    private val strategy: CancelStrategy,
    private val navigator: AuthenticationNavigator,
    private val tokenRepository: TokenRepository,
    private val localRepository: LocalRepository,
    private val settingsInteractor: GetSettingsInteractor,
    private val analyticsManager: AnalyticsManager,
    private val saveCurrentServer: SaveCurrentServerInteractor,
    private val saveAccountInteractor: SaveAccountInteractor,
    private val factory: RocketChatClientFactory,
    val serverInteractor: GetConnectingServerInteractor
) {
    // TODO - we should validate the current server when opening the app, and have a nonnull get()
    private var currentServer = serverInteractor.get()!!
    private val token = tokenRepository.get(currentServer)
    private lateinit var client: RocketChatClient
    private lateinit var settings: PublicSettings

    fun setupView() {
        setupConnectionInfo(currentServer)
        setupForgotPasswordView()
    }

    private fun setupConnectionInfo(serverUrl: String) {
        currentServer = serverUrl
        client = factory.get(currentServer)
        settings = settingsInteractor.get(currentServer)
    }

    private fun setupForgotPasswordView() {
        if (settings.isPasswordResetEnabled()) {
            view.showForgotPasswordView()
        }
    }

    fun authenticateWithUserAndPassword(usernameOrEmail: String, password: String) {
        launchUI(strategy) {
            view.showLoading()
            try {
                val token = retryIO("login") {
                    when {
                        settings.isLdapAuthenticationEnabled() ->
                            client.loginWithLdap(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        usernameOrEmail.isEmail() ->
                            client.loginWithEmail(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        else ->
                            client.login(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                }
                val myself = retryIO("me()") { client.me() }
                myself.username?.let { username ->
                    val user = User(
                        id = myself.id,
                        roles = myself.roles,
                        status = myself.status,
                        name = myself.name,
                        emails = myself.emails?.map { Email(it.address ?: "", it.verified) },
                        username = username,
                        utcOffset = myself.utcOffset
                    )
                    localRepository.saveCurrentUser(currentServer, user)
                    saveCurrentServer.save(currentServer)
                    localRepository.save(LocalRepository.CURRENT_USERNAME_KEY, username)
                    saveAccount(username)
                    saveToken(token)
                    analyticsManager.logLogin(
                        AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                        true
                    )
                    view.saveSmartLockCredentials(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    navigator.toChatList()
                }
            } catch (exception: RocketChatException) {
                when (exception) {
                    is RocketChatTwoFactorException -> {
                        navigator.toTwoFA(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        analyticsManager.logLogin(
                            AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                            false
                        )
                        exception.message?.let {
                            view.showMessage(it)
                        }.ifNull {
                            view.showGenericErrorMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                view.hideLoading()
            }
        }

    }

    fun forgotPassword() = navigator.toForgotPassword()

    private fun saveAccount(username: String) {
        val icon = settings.favicon()?.let {
            currentServer.serverLogoUrl(it)
        }
        val logo = settings.wideTile()?.let {
            currentServer.serverLogoUrl(it)
        }
        val thumb = currentServer.avatarUrl(username, token?.userId, token?.authToken)
        val account = Account(
            settings.siteName() ?: currentServer,
            currentServer,
            icon,
            logo,
            username,
            thumb
        )
        saveAccountInteractor.save(account)
    }

    private fun saveToken(token: Token) = tokenRepository.save(currentServer, token)
}
```

LoginPresenterTest

```
class LoginPresenterTest {

    lateinit var loginPresenter: LoginPresenter

    private val view = mock(LoginView::class.java)
    private val strategy = mock(CancelStrategy::class.java)
    private val navigator = mock(AuthenticationNavigator::class.java)
    private val tokenRepository = mock(TokenRepository::class.java)
    private val localRepository = mock(LocalRepository::class.java)
    private val settingsInteractor = mock(GetSettingsInteractor::class.java)
    private val analyticsManager = mock(AnalyticsManager::class.java)
    private val saveCurrentServer = mock(SaveCurrentServerInteractor::class.java)
    private val saveAccountInteractor = mock(SaveAccountInteractor::class.java)
    private val factory = mock(RocketChatClientFactory::class.java)
    private val serverInteractor = mock(GetConnectingServerInteractor::class.java)
    private val token = mock(Token::class.java)
    private lateinit var settings: PublicSettings

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        loginPresenter = LoginPresenter(
            view, strategy, navigator, tokenRepository, localRepository, settingsInteractor,
            analyticsManager, saveCurrentServer, saveAccountInteractor, factory, serverInteractor
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun testAttach() {
        loginPresenter.setupView()
        assertNotNull(view)
    }
}
```

But on running the test I am getting KotlinNullPointerException as the variable current server is becoming null because there is no url saved in it. Is there any way I can avoid it from being null during running test. I have tried using elvis operator and modify LoginPresenter but I want to know is there anything other way which can work. I just want to initialise the value of current server with any url string to avoid NPE during running tests.

```
private var currentServer = serverInteractor.get()?: "https://example.com"
```

I also have SaveConnectingServerInteractor and GetConnectingServerInteractor  which is used to store the server url at the time of authentication.

```
class SaveConnectingServerInteractor @Inject constructor(
    @ForAuthentication private val repository: CurrentServerRepository
) {
    fun save(url: String) = repository.save(url)
}

class GetConnectingServerInteractor @Inject constructor(
    @ForAuthentication private val repository: CurrentServerRepository
) {
    fun get(): String? = repository.get()

    fun clear() {
        repository.clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
@Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        whenever(serverInteractor.get()).thenReturn("http://fakeurl")
        loginPresenter = LoginPresenter(
            view, strategy, navigator, tokenRepository, localRepository, settingsInteractor,
            analyticsManager, saveCurrentServer, saveAccountInteractor, factory, serverInteractor
        )
    }
```

The `whenever` method is from https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin.

EDIT:
Alternatively, you can also use `when` keyword if you don't want a dependency on mockito-kotlin-

```
`when`(serverInteractor.get()).thenReturn("http://fakeurl")
```

Comment: Yes it indeed solved my problem. Can you please modified your answer to use `when`(serverInteractor.get()).thenReturn("http://fakeurl") so I can accept your ans as it is supported by official mockito library.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem in case of UI tests I have tried this solution there but then I am getting another error. Can you have a look at it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56493147/8549281

Answer (score 1):

Answer by VishalHemnani really helps me but if someone does not want to use https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin and is using the official mockito library. In that case, this will work

```
@Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        `when`(serverInteractor.get()).thenReturn("http://fakeurl")
        loginPresenter = LoginPresenter(
            view, strategy, navigator, tokenRepository, localRepository, settingsInteractor,
            analyticsManager, saveCurrentServer, saveAccountInteractor, factory, serverInteractor
        )
    }
```