# How to initialize nullable variable of presenter through espresso UI test to avoid NPE

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso

I am trying to write Espresso UI test for an android app build with kotlin. I have written a basic UI test to test the UI elements present in the loginFragment.

```
@LargeTest
class LoginFragmentTest {

    private val serverUrl = "https://example.com"

    @JvmField
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(AuthenticationActivity::class.java, true, true)

    @Rule
    fun rule() = activityRule

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        rule().activity.addFragmentBackStack(ScreenViewEvent.Login.screenName, R.id.fragment_container) {
            newInstance(serverUrl)
        }      
    }


    @Test
    fun check_UI_elements(){
        onView(withId(R.id.text_login)).check(matches(withText("Login")))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_username_or_email)).check(matches(withHint("Username or email")))
        onView(withId(R.id.text_password)).check(matches(withHint("Password")))
        onView(withId(R.id.button_log_in)).check(matches(withText("Login")))
        onView(withId(R.id.button_forgot_your_password)).check(matches(withText("Forgot your password?")))
    }
```

Login Fragment

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment(), LoginView {
    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: LoginPresenter
    @Inject
    lateinit var analyticsManager: AnalyticsManager
    private var serverName: String? = null
    private val editTextsDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)

        arguments?.run {
            serverName = getString(SERVER_NAME)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = container?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authentication_log_in)

.....
}
```

Login Presenter

```
class LoginPresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val view: LoginView,
    private val strategy: CancelStrategy,
    private val navigator: AuthenticationNavigator,
    private val tokenRepository: TokenRepository,
    private val localRepository: LocalRepository,
    private val settingsInteractor: GetSettingsInteractor,
    private val analyticsManager: AnalyticsManager,
    private val saveCurrentServer: SaveCurrentServerInteractor,
    private val saveAccountInteractor: SaveAccountInteractor,
    private val factory: RocketChatClientFactory,
    val serverInteractor: GetConnectingServerInteractor
) {
    // TODO - we should validate the current server when opening the app, and have a nonnull get()
    private var currentServer = serverInteractor.get()!!
    private val token = tokenRepository.get(currentServer)
    private lateinit var client: RocketChatClient
    private lateinit var settings: PublicSettings

    fun setupView() {
        setupConnectionInfo(currentServer)
        setupForgotPasswordView()
    }

...
}
```

I also have SaveConnectingServerInteractor and GetConnectingServerInteractor which is used to store the server url at the time of authentication.

```
open class SaveConnectingServerInteractor @Inject constructor(
        @ForAuthentication private val repository: CurrentServerRepository
    ) {
        fun save(url: String) = repository.save(url)
    }
open class GetConnectingServerInteractor @Inject constructor(
    @ForAuthentication private val repository: CurrentServerRepository
) {
    fun get(): String? = repository.get()

    fun clear() {
        repository.clear()
    }
}
```

LoginFragmentModule

```
@Module
class LoginFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    fun loginView(frag: LoginFragment): LoginView = frag

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    fun provideLifecycleOwner(frag: LoginFragment): LifecycleOwner = frag
}
```

LoginFragmentProvider

```
@Module abstract class LoginFragmentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [LoginFragmentModule::class])
    @PerFragment
    abstract fun provideLoginFragment(): LoginFragment
}
```

But on running the test I am getting KotlinNullPointerException as the variable currentServer is becoming null because there is no url saved in it. Is there any way I can avoid it from being null during running UI test. I have tried using elvis operator and modify LoginPresenter but I want to know is there anything other way which can work. I just want to initialize the value of current server with any URL string to avoid NPE during running tests.

I have also tried using

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    `when`(serverInteractor.get()).thenReturn("http://fakeurl")`
    rule().activity.addFragmentBackStack(ScreenViewEvent.Login.screenName, R.id.fragment_container) {
        newInstance(serverUrl)
    }      
}
```

but then it is throwing

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String chat.rocket.android.server.domain.CurrentServerRepository.get()' on a null object reference
at chat.rocket.android.server.domain.GetConnectingServerInteractor.get(GetConnectingServerInteractor.kt:9)
at chat.rocket.android.authentication.login.ui.LoginFragmentTest.setUp(LoginFragmentTest.kt:42)
```

Comment: Can you also add the code for your Dagger component and modules?
Hard to speculate without that.

Comment: Sure, I have added LoginFragmentModule and LoginFragmentProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should inject mocked version of presenter into the fragment for test purposes.
You could follow this:
https://proandroiddev.com/writing-espresso-instrumentation-tests-with-dagger2-kotlin-d30f12c4769b
or just documentation:
https://square.github.io/dagger/#using (Module Overrides)